# Summing specific columns in a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to sum specific columns in a panda dataframe.  I'm starting with text in the dataframe, given specific words I change the text to a number and then carry out my sum.

I start by creating a sample DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,'produces','produces','understands','produces'], 'b' : [2,'','produces','understands','understands'], 'c' : [3,'','','understands','']})
transposed_df = df.transpose()
transposed_df
```

Output:

```
   0         1         2            3            4
a  1  produces  produces  understands     produces
b  2            produces  understands  understands
c  3                      understands
```

This is all good and what I expect.  I then change the relevant text to integers and create a dataframe of (mostly) integers.

```
measure1 = transposed_df.iloc[:,[0,1,2]].replace('produces',1)
measure2 = transposed_df.iloc[:,[0,3]].replace('understands',1)
measure3 = transposed_df.iloc[:,[0,4]].replace('produces',1)

measures = [measure1, measure2, measure3]

from functools import reduce
counter = reduce (lambda left, right: pd.merge(left,right), measures)

counter
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3            4
0  1  1  1  1            1
1  2     1  1  understands
2  3        1
```

This is what I expect.

I then try to sum columns 1 and 2 across each row and add it back into transposed_df

```
transposed_df['first']=counter.iloc[:,[1,2]].sum(axis=1)
transposed_df
```

Output:

```
   0         1         2            3            4  first
a  1  produces  produces  understands     produces    NaN
b  2            produces  understands  understands    NaN
c  3                      understands                 NaN
```

I am expecting the final column to be 2,1, 0.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the `dtypes` of your columns, also check the index that you are trying to assign to your old frame.

Comment: I'm not a big user of Pandas.  Could you give me a little more detail

Comment: probably has something do with index. counter.iloc[:,[1,2]].sum(axis=1) does not have the same index as transposed_df. Pandas will try to align the index when assining values

Comment: Maybe it will help if you could explain, given original data sample, what you want to compute. Your introduction is halfway in and it seems your dataframe is not tidy.  It seems you are working pandas in a way it was not intended to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems: the summation and the insertion of a column with different indexes.

### 1) Summation

Your `df` is of type `objects` (all strings, including empty strings). The dataframe `counter` is of mixed types too (ints and strings):

```
counter.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 5 columns):
0    3 non-null int64
1    3 non-null object
2    3 non-null object
3    3 non-null int64
4    3 non-null object
dtypes: int64(2), object(3)
```

keeping in mind that:

> Columns with mixed types are stored with the object dtype. [see `dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html)

So although the first line of `counters` contains two integers, they belong to series (columns) of type `object` and pandas doen't like to sum them up (you're obviously using a pandas version below 0.22.0, in later versions the result is 0.0 with the default `min_count=0`, see [sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)). You can see this by

```
counter.iloc[:,[1,2]].applymap(type)

               1              2
0  <class 'int'>  <class 'int'>
1  <class 'str'>  <class 'int'>
2  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
```

So the solution would be to explicitely cast objects to numerical where possible (i.e. where the whole row is made up of integers, and not empty strings and integers):

```
counter.iloc[:,[1,2]].apply(lambda x: sum(pd.to_numeric(x)), axis=1)
```

Result:

```
0    2.0
1    NaN
2    NaN
```

### 2) Column insertion

There are different indexes:

```
counter.index
# Int64Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='int64')
transposed_df.index
# Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')
```

Therefore you get all Nans with your method. The easiest way to do it is to insert just the values of the series instead of the series itself (where pandas aligns the index:

```
transposed_df['first'] = counter.iloc[:,[1,2]].apply(lambda x: sum(pd.to_numeric(x)), axis=1).to_list()
```

Result:

```
   0         1         2            3            4  first
a  1  produces  produces  understands     produces    2.0
b  2            produces  understands  understands    NaN
c  3                      understands                 NaN
```

Comment: thanks.  This has me on the right track and I now have `counter.iloc[:,[1,2]].apply(lambda x: sum(pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')), axis=1).fillna(0).astype(np.int64).to_list()` which is giving me the results I'm after